# what do this code do? this code from thingengineer? the array one i can't understand

Tags: php, mysql

this code from thing engineer

```
  $cols = Array ("id", "name", "email");
    $users = $db->get ("users", null, $cols);
    if ($db->count > 0)
        foreach ($users as $user) { 
            print_r ($user);
        }
```

can someone explain it to me? thanks a lot

Comment: This entirely depends on what `$db` is and what `$db->get()` does with its arguments. Given the variable names, I'd assume it accepts an array of column names to use in a `SELECT` query

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Codeigniter.

Fetches 3 columns from table "users" of the active database and if at least one row was provided, iterate over them and print the row.